# how can i color specific pixels in matplotlib imshow?

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, imshow

I am plotting a `numpy` matrix with `imshow` and nearest neighbor interpolation in blue scale.

How can i color specific pixels in the plot so that they would be, say red?

```
pyplot.imshow(matrix, interpolation='nearest',cmap = cm.Blues)
pyplot.show()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't directly color pixels red with a colormap that doesn't have red in it. You could pick a red-blue colormap and norm your matrix data into the blue part, but you can also just plot over an imshow image:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
from numpy.random import random
matrix = random((12,12))

from matplotlib import cm
pyplot.imshow(matrix, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cm.Blues)
pyplot.scatter([6,8], [10,7], color='red', s=40)
pyplot.show()
```

[image]