# Shading specific "pixels" a different color in matplotlib's pcolormesh

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

I have a heatmap that I plot with `pcolormesh`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generate random array
array = np.random.rand(10,10)
x = np.arange(0,10)
y = np.arange(0,10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=1)
colormesh = ax.pcolormesh(x,y,array)
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_yticks(y)
cb_ax = fig.add_axes([0.93, 0.1, 0.02, 0.8])
cbar = fig.colorbar(colormesh,cax=cb_ax)
colormesh.set_clim(0,1)
plt.show()
```

I want to select a few pixels and shade them another color that is different from those in the colorbar. Say I set the values of these pixels to `-1`:

```
# chose the pixels to shade
array[5,5] = -1
array[0,7] = -1
```

I don't want to set the colorbar limits from `-1` to `1`, as there is no value in the range `(-1,0)` and this only compresses the range of colors available for the range `[0,1]`.

With this setup, is there a way for me to selectively color those pixels, say, red?

Notes:

- I'm using `pcolormesh` and not `imshow` because in the original data `x` and `y` are not equally spaced.
- I don't want to add a dot on top of the said pixels like [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29155324/how-can-i-color-specific-pixels-in-matplotlib-imshow), but rather want to shade the whole pixel red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a color map with the [`under`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Colormap.html#matplotlib.colors.Colormap.set_under) color set to red. The `vmin` and `vmax` define the range of the normal colors. Values smaller than `vmin` will get the `under` color (the default `under` color is the same as the lowest color in the colorbar).

Instead of `under` (or `over`), you can also set a [`bad`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Colormap.html#matplotlib.colors.Colormap.set_bad) color for values that are `NaN` or `infinity`.

`'viridis'` is matplotlib's default [colormap](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html).

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generate random array
array = np.random.rand(10, 10)
x = np.arange(0, 10)
y = np.arange(0, 10)
cmap = plt.get_cmap('viridis').copy()
cmap.set_under('red')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1)
# chose the pixels to shade
array[5, 5] = -1
array[0, 7] = -1
colormesh = ax.pcolormesh(x, y, array, vmin=0, vmax=1, cmap=cmap)
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_yticks(y)
cbar = fig.colorbar(colormesh)
plt.show()
```

[image: coloring a few pixels in plt.colormesh()]